# How can i scroll the scrollview when click on button above scrollview in ios 7 xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have two buttons.

I also have two screens in scrollview that is one is `UIView` in green color and other is `UIImage` Apple logo. Both display properly but I just take the screen shot like that.

When I click on registration  button then in scrollview display the `UIView` that is the green view!

And when I click on image button it show the `UIImageView` that is Apple logo  .
i take the screen shot like that the scrollview scroll and the green view is uiview and second behind it is image view that contain the image

```
 //help me

 -(IBAction)registrationClick:(id)sender
 {
    NSLog(@"mayank");
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
 }
```

[image: enter image description here i take the screen shot like that the scrollview scroll and the green view is uiview and second behind it is image view that contain the image]

Comment: i want to add the image but its gives me a error like need  10 reoutation etc etc .....

Comment: friends help him by upvoting. i give +1

Comment: now you can add image.

Comment: please answer me ... what i written in registration button and image button method ... And please also define the other method or code that i required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

or if you want to preserve the horizontal scroll position and just reset the vertical position:

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0)
animated:YES];
```